# Dynamically generate mixin using LESS

Tags: internet-explorer, less, mixins, retina

How do you change a mixin dynamically. I'd like to call the less file like this:

```
.sprite-resize(facebook);
```

Then I'm trying to setup my mixing like this:

```
.sprite-resize(@file) {
  @ret: '@sprite-retina-@{file}';
  @norm: '@sprite-@{file}';
  .sprite-ret(@ret);
  .sprite-norm(@norm);
}

.sprite-ret(@ret) {
    @sprite-image: ~`"@{ret}".split(', ')[8].slice(1, -2)`;
    background-image: url(@sprite-image);
}

.sprite-norm(@norm) {
    .lt-ie9 & {
      @sprite-image: ~`"@{norm}".split(', ')[8].slice(1, -2)`;
      background-image: url(@sprite-image);
    }
}
// The @sprite- and @sprite-retina values are automatically generated for me by a grunt plugin: "grunt-spritesmith": "~1.23.0"
@sprite-facebook: 425px 142px -425px -142px 24px 24px 453px 410px '/@{images-dir}/spritesheet-icons159.png';

@sprite-retina-facebook: 25px 147px -25px -147px 24px 24px 209px 189px '/@{images-dir}/spritesheet-icons-retina159.png';
```

But I keep getting errors when I build like: "Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined."

Any idea how I can call one name like "facebook" and run both the retina and non-retina versions of the mixin?

Comment: You get a javascript error (obviously an array returned by `"@sprite-retina-facebook".split(', ')` has no element with index `8` hence the error). I'm not sure why there's inline javascript at all and why it is supposed to perform some array processing since what you need can be achieved with just something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/f7631b866846801a06ee#file-24130053-less) (Though I've no idea what the resulting `url('@sprite-retina-facebook')` is supposed to mean, is the `@sprite-retina-facebook` actually a variable?).

Comment: What are the values of `@sprite-retina-facebook` and  `@sprite-facebook`?

Comment: I've added the values of `@sprite-retina-facebook` and `@sprite-facebook` to help clarify. I'm using [spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-spritesmith) to generate these values.

Comment: See the "[referencing a variable by name](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names)" section then, e.g. the `@ret` should be defined as `@ret: 'sprite-retina-@{file}';` and `.sprite-ret` invoked as `.sprite-ret(@@ret);`, notice the double `@`. Same for `@norm`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thank you! Your two comments worked like a charm to fix this!